# Как сделать exe из кода на javascript?

Tags: javascript

Написал рабочий код, для будущей программы (автопостер на доски), юзаю его через редактор js от мозилы. Хочу сделать программу для пк (.exe формата), но как и в чем лучше делать оболочку для моего кода?

Comment: "гетелементбилд" - `-1`

Comment: @Igor Кроме сарказма, ответа на вопросы нет? исправил.

Comment: `учу только джаву` – Java ≠ JavaScript.

Comment: @NickVolynkin прошу прощения, благодарю за редактирование объявления. Первый раз у вас.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, над бы и название вопроса изменить

Comment: У вас тут два вопроса. Выделите из них один, пожалуйста. Второй можно опубликовать отдельно.

Comment: @vikttur когда  автор выберет, какой вопрос оставить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin оставил 1 вопрос.

Comment: @vikttur есть заголовок. )

Comment: Никак. Юзайте селениум )

Answer (score 3):

Ключ для поиска: "javascript desktop".
Сейчас самый популярный фреймворк для написания десктопных приложений с помощью JavaScript это [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/).